# !] No podspec found for `Example_Framework` in `.`

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

i am trying to install a  [SideMenu](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu) library via `pod` but facing problem to install,

I am using Following dependancy in the pod file,

```
# platform :ios, '9.0'

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
target 'SwiftSideMenu' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  # Pods for SwiftSideMenu

  pod "SideMenu", :path => "."

end
```

Following issue appears on terminal while installation,

[Terminal issue log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9gs3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have forgotten to add podspace metadata files like,add following files from [Sidemenu](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu) at project level i mean where you have put podfile.

LICENSE ~> Info related weather framework is free or not (i.e public or private)

README.md ~> [Info](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/1703a3464674baecf54bd7e766f4b37ed8fc43f7/README.md)

SideMenu.podspec ~> [Info](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html)

Otherwise, you can install directly without taking `.podspec` file too if they have mentioned license is free & public.

```
pod "SideMenu"
```

Comment: hey hi second option works for me but what it indicate the podspec file in the project exactly?